# Can anyone tell me why someone doing plumbing work might call something a "lake of fire"?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe

I overheard a conversation where a plumber was talking to a coworker. He was frustrated seeming and said something about being annoyed at the maintenance manager or property manager at the large 20 story apartment complex in downtown Los Angeles where I live.

The plumber said, "that place is a lake of fire."

I wasn't really able to stand around too long to listen to everything he said but that was the end of the sentence and he didn't explain what he meant by that before or after really.  I think it was in reference to the property manager not wanting to do something that needed to be addressed.

.

Does anyone have any idea or guess why a plumber would call something a "lake of fire"? Is there anything to do with plumbing that would make this analogy make sense?

The obvious imagery of a lake on fire or and a plumber having anything to do with fire is somewhat bizarre. I'd appreciate any input even if it seems unlikely. Please consider the question as it relates to an apartment home improvement topic and the general home improvement topic of plumbing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement.

Comment: Have you tried an image search for [`lake of fire`](https://www.google.com/search?q=lake+of+fire&tbm=isch)?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this question has been answered under the etymology tag on the english stack, but he is probably saying the installation is hell for trades to work for, and that may also imply something about the quality of product, whether good or bad.

Comment: Not a home improvement question but in this context I believe the term "lake of fire" is synonymous with "Hell".  That comes from the Bible such as Revelation 20:10.  I'd interpret the plumbers comments to indicate that the place he was referring to is a plumber's nightmare.  It's not exactly clear why, perhaps the existing work is substandard, the tenants are uncooperative, or the management is difficult to work with.

Answer (score 3):

This adage has nothing specific to do with plumbing. It is a Biblical reference from Revelation 20:10 "And the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are, and shall be tormented day and night for ever and ever." What he is referring to is a job that will never be correct and result in constant call backs. In other words every aspect of the job results in some unseen issue that must be corrected first.